# PHP MySQL query not returning records

Tags: php, mysql

I know this may sound like duplicate but it's not. I'm trying to do a simple SELECT query on a mysql table through PHP. This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$RTC_DB = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'telemedia-arte', 'rtc')
    or die("Erro na ligação.. ".mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_set_charset('utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
if (!$RTC_DB) {
    echo "error";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'prof' WHERE passo = 2";
    $videos = mysqli_query($RTC_DB, $query);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($videos) > 0) {
        echo "Woo!";
        while ($video = mysqli_fetch_assoc($videos)) {
           $video_courses[$video["id_aula"]] = $video["tituloaula"];
        }
    }

mysqli_close($RTC_DB);
}
?>
```

If the query returns at least one record, it will output "Woo!", but it's not. I tried the query in phpmyadmin and it works.

Can anybody please help me with this? I'm getting very worried with this.

Thanks in advance
Pedro

Comment: I think you need to do `mysqli_affected_rows($RTC_DB)`

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: You're using the incorrect [identifier qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

Comment: Pedro - try something like this:

   $query = "SELECT * FROM prof WHERE pass = '2'";
   $result = $mysqli->query($query);
   if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    echo $query->num_rows. " records found - Whoo!<br><br>";
    while ($video = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $video['id_aula']." ".$video['tituloula']."<br>";    
    }
   } else {
    echo "No records found";
   }